# How to add pictures around a background through CSS?

Tags: css, html, image, background

I'm really working hard on this thing but I can't figure out how to create this through CSS.

Basically on this [website here](http://frenchegg.com) I'm trying to add images to go outside of the main-content background as you can see on this image below. Where it says "Lattest Lessons" (sorry for the typo) or where it says Receive our newsletter.

Does anybody have a club? I'm lost!

Here is some code:

```
.main-content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    padding:1em 0 8.5em 0;
    background:#fff;
}

.main-content p {
    color:#555;
}

.site-wrap {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you looked here, its similar idea http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Can you either accept an answer or provide more direction on question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is creating a div in the background that looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="backgrounddiv">
</div>
```

So the HTML is really easy. Don't put anything in those divs. Now for the CSS:

CSS:

```
    #backgrounddiv {
length:100%; //spans length of page
width:100%;  //spans width of page
z-index:1;   //makes sure background is behind all the other objects
background-color: #000; //black background
position: absolute; //isn't affected or doesn't get affected by other elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're likely looking for is positioning the element correctly. This can either be relative or absolute positioning based on your needs. In either case, ensure that the PARENT container is a positioned element (in your example it is: relative)

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/callseng/UUxqG/

The paragraph with class 'move-left' is housed inside of the main-content element, it is relatively positioned and then pushed to the left by 25px.

```
position:relative;
left: -25px;
```